# How to categorize elements of array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem regarding arrays.

So, I have an array with the size of `255` (let's call it `array(255)`). I have an `integer` named `block` also.

I want to categorize this arrays (I hope the term is right).

What I want is:

If the chosen array element is

```
From (0-63)   , block = 0  
From (64-127) , block = 1  
From (128-191), block = 2  
From (192-255), block = 3
```

I know with this case I can just use if statement. But what if I scale up my array size into thousands?

I can't use rows of If statement.

Is there any simpler and more efficient solution for this?

Comment: you must find a formula and then use it in your program.

Comment: @4386427 Mean you `block = index / 64;`...? ;)

Comment: @LPs Thanks a lot man I didn't think of that.

Comment: @LPs oh, dear - my bad :(   yes, I did intend to use `/` but wrote `%` instead.... comment deleted...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with an integer division:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t array[255] = {0};

    srand(time(NULL));   

    for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 256;

        printf("Array[%zu]= %"PRIu8"\tblock= %"PRIu8"\n", i, array[i], array[i] / 64 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
int array[255];

...

int getArrayItemByCateg(int category, int index) {
    return array[category * 64 + index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only an pointer to your element in your code you could use something like the following function:

```
int getBlock(void* array, void* arrayElement, size_t size)
{
    return (int)((arrayElement - array) / (size * 64)); 
}
```

This function can be uses for different array types but the origin array has to be known when you are calling this function. See the following examples:

```
uint32_t array_u32[256];
uint16_t array_u16[256];

printf("array u32 index 32 is block %d\n", getBlock(array_u32, &array_u32[32], sizeof(array_u32[0])));
printf("array u32 index 129 is block %d\n", getBlock(array_u32, &array_u32[129], sizeof(array_u32[0])));

printf("array u16 index 32 is block %d\n", getBlock(array_u16, &array_u16[32], sizeof(array_u16[0])));
printf("array u16 index 129 is block %d\n", getBlock(array_u16, &array_u16[129], sizeof(array_u16[0])));
```

The following result will be printed:

```
array u32 index 32 is block 0
array u32 index 129 is block 2
array u16 index 32 is block 0
array u16 index 129 is block 2
```

Also see the code at [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/WJRsul).

Answer (score 0):

How about a multidimensional array? Information: [Tutorials Point - Multidimensional Arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm)

This may not be an elegant solution but it is pretty simple. This may not be ideal for larger scale data however larger scale data may be best using a binary or quad tree anyhoo.

Multidimensional Array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int COLUMN_SIZE = 64;
const int ROW_SIZE = 4;

// Access index of row using the labels below
const int BLOCK_ONE = 0;
const int BLOCK_TWO = 1;
const int BLOCK_THREE = 2;
const int BLOCK_FOUR = 3;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int array[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE] = {0};

  srand(time(NULL));

  /* Initialise array */
  for(int x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < COLUMN_SIZE; i++) {
      array[x][i] = rand() % (ROW_SIZE * COLUMN_SIZE);
    }
  }

  /* Test */
  for(int x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < COLUMN_SIZE; i++) {
      printf("Array[%d][%d]: %d\n", x, i, array[x][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```